# Create an "Import Menu" in TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript

I'm trying to work on a project with a numerous amount of files, and I thought an import object would be helpful. For example, here would be `menu.ts` on the top-level, which every program will reference to:

```js
import router from "./router/index";
import controllers from "./controllers/index";
import config from "./config";

export default {
  router: router,
  controllers: controllers
  config: config
}
```

This would be a sample `controllers/index.ts`:

```js
import database from "./database";
import accounts from "./accounts";
import a_controller from "./a_controller";

export default {
  database: database,
  accounts: accounts,
  a_controller: a_controller
}
```

Obviously, this would raise some circular dependency issues with controllers referencing to menu. This is asserted with a `TypeError: cannot read property controllers of undefined` error message. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

in your case it is better to use named import, in controllers/index.ts: you can do like:

```js
export { database } from "./database";
export { accounts } from "./accounts";
export { a_controller } from "./a_controller";
```

and in your menu.ts you can import them like:

```js
import { database, accounts, a_controller } from './controller'
```

Comment: For the first example, is there a way to use the default export? Using `export * as accounts from "./accounts"` does not work.